# Restirct Google CLoud Storage bucket access to a specific domain name

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Does anyone know how I could allow bucket objects be read/viewed - only through a specific website ? Without having to make the bucket public, using allUsers !?

I tried adding the domain name as a Principal and gave it the Storage Legacy Object Reader role. That though, did not work as planned. It actually just blocks all access. I need something like allUsers but only when the objects are being called from a specific domain.

Comment: What do you mean by "from a specific domain"?  Access to a bucket doesn't have to come from any "domain" at all. The originator just needs an IP address with an internet connection, and it's impossible to fully ensure, by any means that would be considered "secure", that IP is linked to any given internet domain.  This is why GCP has IAM - a system of authorization that **is** considered secure.  allUsers is just a part of the larger IAM scheme that you need to familiarize yourself if you want to control access to a GCP resource.

Comment: I have a website **example.com** . That website calls a google cloud storage bucket for files that are shown on the website. In Network inspector all the GET requests a listed - anyone could then copy the link and paste in a browser and access the files. What I would like to do is ensure that the only time the files can be accessed is when on the website. i.e. only to present the files in the context of the website. I don't want anyone to be able to access the files with a direct link, that would be shown with network analyzer.

Comment: It's not possible as long as you're allowing direct access.  You will need to implement some middleware that performs any necessary checks. Even better, you should strongly consider implementing per-user access and use your middleware to determine if the **user** should be able to access the content, not any sense of origin or hostname, which could be spoofable.